# bunch of 404 errors when trying to update debian installation

Tags: linux, debian, installation, upgrade

Trying to update my distro, get a bunch of 404 errors when trying to upgrade.

I'm also trying to get GLIBCXX_3.4.21 installed, anyone know what I need to do?  I only have GLIBCXX_3.4.20 installed.
*EDIT I've managed to upgrade glibc using a package, it is just the 404 error issue that persists now.

I've included the update and upgrade output [here](https://pastebin.com/QQN6VXDF), although it may have cut & pasted wrongly.

```
testing
```

Comment: These backports have been removed from the server. Check this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure that link contains instructions on how to change the repository.  I don't know how to do that.